# Firebase google sign in build failed

Tags: firebase, flutter

Made a google signin app with firebase

pubspec.yaml:
firebase_auth:
google_sign_in:

console message:

```
  Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':firebase_auth'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':firebase_auth:classpath'.
   > Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\fidel\.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.71\descriptors\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\475b59a03ea03e6388c8f34eee6a9d08\descriptor.bin
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':firebase_auth' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to /.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn

Delete shared_preferences

Execute this command to refresh your packages:

```
flutter packages get
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in

> Flutter Project -> Android -> settings.gradle

```
def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```